# Inference Time TensorFlow C++ API vs Python API

Tags: tensorflow

In the inference mode, Is C++ API faster than Python API? In the some issues, I've seen the C++ slower than python, why? Is this right?

**OS : Ubuntu 16.04**

**Tensorflow : 1.12.0 binary**

**CUDA/CUDNN : 9.0 / 7.0**

[Issue 1](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/22852)

[Issue 2](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15552)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do few warm-up predictions. After the second or third prediction, you will notice the time will decrease.